# C# Function Awareness?

Tags: c#, multithreading, function

In a multi-thread app. is there a way to programatically have thread-B check what function thead-A is currently in?

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285031/how-to-get-non-current-threads-stacktrace

Answer (score 5):

You can get a stack trace of another thread by doing this:

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(myThread);
```

From this you can get the call stack, and the function it's currently executing.

Comment: It's worth noting that I don't know if there are any threading issues you may encounter by doing this.

Comment: The other SO question says Suspend/Resume needs to be called.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that should be built in to the application itself in order to avoid possible contention between threads.

In my opinion, a thread should never control the execution of another (e.g., suspend/resume), except for starting it. They should merely suggest that the other thread control *itself* (with mutexes and events, for example). That greatly simplifies thread management and reduces the possibility of race conditions.

If you really want thread B to know what thread A is currently doing, thread A should be communicating that to thread B (or any other thread such as the main thread below) using, as an example, a mutex-protected string with the function name in it. Something along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
global string threadAFunc = ""
global mutex mutexA
global boolean stopA

function main:
    stopA = false
    init mutexA
    start threadA
    do until 20 minutes have passed:
        claim mutexA
        print "Thread A currently in " + threadAFunc
        release mutexA
    stopA = true
    join threadA
    return
```

```
function threadA:
    string oldThreadAFunc = threadAFunc
    claim mutexA
    threadAFunc = "threadA"
    release mutexA

    while not stopA:
        threadASub

    claim mutexA
    threadAFunc = oldThreadAFunc
    release mutexA
    return

function threadASub:
    string oldThreadAFunc = threadAFunc
    claim mutexA
    threadAFunc = "threadASub"
    release mutexA

    // Do something here.

    claim mutexA
    threadAFunc = oldThreadAFunc
    release mutexA
    return
```

This method can be used in *any* language or environment that supports threading, not just .Net or C#. Each function in thread A has prolog and epilog code to save, set and restore the values used in other threads.