# How to print the current Stack Trace in .NET without any exception?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, stack-trace, printstacktrace

I have a regular C# code. ***I have no exceptions***. I want to programmatically log the current stack trace for debugging purpose. Example:

```
public void executeMethod() 
{
    logStackTrace();
    method();
}
```

Answer (score 512, accepted):

Have a look at the [`System.Diagnostics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics) namespace.  Lots of goodies in there!

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
```

This is really good to have a poke around in to learn what's going on under the hood.

I'd recommend that you have a look into logging solutions (Such as NLog, log4net or the Microsoft patterns and practices Enterprise Library) which may achieve your purposes and then some.

Comment: Keep in mind that `StackTrace` is **dog slow** - so use it sparingly.

Comment: I think your answer should mention that you can use `t.ToString()` to get a string representation of the stack trace, which is probably what the OP wanted.

Comment: If someone want File Name and File line numbers. You must at least call `new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true)`.

Answer (score 273):

An alternative to `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` is to use [System.Environment.StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace) which returns a string-representation of the stacktrace.

Another useful option is to use the `$CALLER` and `$CALLSTACK` [debugging variables in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints#BKMK_Print_to_the_Output_window_with_tracepoints) since this can be enabled run-time without rebuilding the application.

Comment: `Environment.StackTrace` just new's up an instance of `StackTrace`.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, but `System.Environment.StackTrace` might be a more convenient way of accessing that information.

Comment: True. But if you need to skip a frame or omit file info you'll have to use `StackTrace` directly.

Comment: @AndreiRinea: Actually, I belive you can access line numbers using `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilelinenumber.aspx

Comment: Isn't it annoying that `Environment.StackTrace` always starts out with `at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()`? That's not part of the current stack trace as at the point that someone's looking for it.

Comment: @Rory, have a look at the constructor StackTrace(int skipFrames, bool fNeedFileInfo), you can skip the starting frame. ipen the method in ILSpy and you can see what it does

Comment: I get `StackTrace is a type which isn't valid in the given context.`

Answer (score 40):

There are two ways to do this. The `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()` will give you a stack trace for the current thread. If you have a reference to a `Thread` instance, you can get the stack trace for that via the overloaded version of `StackTrace()`.

You may also want to check out Stack Overflow question *[How to get non-current thread's stacktrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285031/how-to-get-non-current-threads-stacktrace/528043#528043)*.

Comment: Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'StackTrace' cannot be used like a method.

Answer (score 18):

You can also do this in the Visual Studio debugger without modifying the code.

1. Create a breakpoint where you want to see the stack trace.
2. Right-click the breakpoint and select "Actions..." in VS2015.  In VS2010, select "When Hit...", then enable "Print a message".
3. Make sure "Continue execution" is selected.
4. Type in some text you would like to print out.
5. Add $CALLSTACK wherever you want to see the stack trace.
6. Run the program in the debugger.

Of course, this doesn't help if you're running the code on a different machine, but it can be quite handy to be able to spit out a stack trace automatically without affecting release code or without even needing to restart the program.

Comment: If you want to see a stack trace and you're already in the VS debugger at a breakpoint, just go to Debug->Windows->Call Stack.

Comment: Yes, but if you do it this way, the program doesn't have to stop for you to see the stack trace.

Answer (score 17):

```
Console.WriteLine(
    new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString()
    );
```

The output will be similar to:

> at YourNamespace.Program.executeMethod(String msg)
>
> at YourNamespace.Program.Main(String[] args)

Replace `Console.WriteLine` with your `Log` method. Actually, there is
no need for `.ToString()` for the Console.WriteLine case as it accepts
`object`. But you may need that for your Log(string msg) method.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
Debug.WriteLine(Environment.StackTrace);
```

Answer (score -7):

```
   private void ExceptionTest()
    {
        try
        {
            int j = 0;
            int i = 5;
            i = 1 / j;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            var stList = ex.StackTrace.ToString().Split('\\');
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred at " + stList[stList.Count() - 1]);
        }
    }
```

Seems to work for me

Comment: This is just generating an obvious exception. Why? Why not simply explicitly instantiate an exception, rather than a flaw that will raise an exception in and of itself? What's the benefit of the additional catch logic required to get to the actual exception? And even then, you're still ignoring the actual posted question on how to get a stack trace **without any exception** (read the title).

Comment: it's a valid answer, but a god awful solution. NOONE SHOULD USE IT... @Jeff wherever you done that, replace it with a descent code like the other answers suggested.