# Getting the Stacktrace

Tags: c#, debugging, stack-trace, printstacktrace

When Exception happens you can print out the StackTrace and review it.

What if you want to get the StackTrace without an exception happening?

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

You can print out the stacktrace at any time by calling [Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx)

```
string tracktrace = System.Environment.StackTrace;
```

Answer (score 9):

When you catch an exception you can construct [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(VS.71).aspx) object and extract useful information from it. See the following example:

```
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
        for(int i =0; i< st.FrameCount; i++ )
        {
            // Note that high up the call stack, there is only
            // one stack frame.
            StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(i);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("High up the call stack, Method: {0}",
                sf.GetMethod());

            Console.WriteLine("High up the call stack, Line Number: {0}",
                sf.GetFileLineNumber());
        }
```

PS: This works even without an exception -- see [How to print the current stack trace in .NET without any exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531695/how-to-print-the-current-stack-trace-in-net-without-any-exception).

Answer (score 1):

System.Environment.StackTrace is an awesome tool, but be aware that you don't always get what you're looking for and there are differences between x86 and x64 platforms that can affect the output.  [Grody details here](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2008/11/24/stupid-nunit-tricks-3-foiled.aspx).