# StackTrace returns nothing

Tags: c#, exception

We are having a windows service, which download files from an FTP location.
If there is an exception we are sending email

But StackTrace returns nothing.

```
 public void Send_Mail(string strTitle, Exception ex, string MsgSubject)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.StackTrace StackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex,true);
            StringBuilder msgBody = null;
            msgBody = new StringBuilder();
            msgBody.Append(ex.Message);
            try
            {
                if (StackTrace.FrameCount > 0)
                {
                    foreach (StackFrame r in StackTrace.GetFrames())
                    {
                        msgBody.Append(String.Format("Filename: {0} Line: {1} Column: {2} Offset: {3} Method: {4} <br/> ",
                            r.GetFileName(), r.GetFileLineNumber(), r.GetFileColumnNumber(), r.GetILOffset(), r.GetMethod()));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exMail)
            {

            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this optimized\Release code? StackTrace has much less information when running with optimized\Release code.

Comment: see if this is help ful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620959/getting-the-stacktrace

Comment: Was that exception ever actually thrown?