# Programmatically get C# Stack Trace

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print the current Stack Trace in .NET without any exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531695/how-to-print-the-current-stack-trace-in-net-without-any-exception)

When an exception is thrown, its text contains the stack trace. Can I somehow obtain the stack trace text(including file and line) without exceptions?

```
public void f()
{
   //blah
   string stacktrace = ???;
   //blah
}
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx) or [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) if you need a more convenient (i.e. not string) representation

Answer (score 22):

Yes ...

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           // get call stack
StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames()
```

Answer (score 15):

```
string stackTrace = Environment.StackTrace;
```