# Get Current Call Stack

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, callstack

Is there a possibility to get the current call stack in windows store apps, without throwing an exception?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531695/how-to-print-the-current-stack-trace-in-net-without-any-exception) but it doesn't apply to windows store apps.

*Why do I need this*

I need to get the call stack, because I have a DirectX texture memory leak.

I want to attach the call stack to my textures when I allocate them. After some program use I print the callstacks of all textures that have not been deallocated.

It should be very easy to see where I forgot to deallocate textures.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no documented way for gaining access to the current stack like exists in .NET (like with `StackFrame`).

You could try to maintain a log or record of the execution yourself by creating a function which records the operations. It would require a little bit of pasting into functions:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void Log(string message, 
      [CallerMemberName] string member = "", 
      [CallerFilePath] string path = "", 
      [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0 ) {
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}:{3} ({2}) ", 
         message, member, path, line));
}
```

Using...

```
Log("hello!");
```

Would produce:

```
hello!  MainPage_Loaded:45 (c:\Dev\Projects\Win8AppTest\MainPage.xaml.cs)
```

The above function uses several relatively recent attributes you can use. For example: [`CallerMemberName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5.1%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true). That function obtains the method or property name of the caller.

The `Conditional` attribute just says to only compile the function in DEBUG builds.