# How to view detailed call stack to identify each class used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Off late I have been working on a lot of products developed in .Net platform using various frameworks (ASP.Net Web Forms, ASP.Net MVC, Sharepoint) which were developed by other people who are not around any more. The problem is that a lot of time I have to debug some areas of these apps and I wonder if there is any tool/method that can show me the complete stack of every class and method that was involved. For example I want to click on some button and then see exactly which classes and methods were invoked. This can be partially done using call stack but you can only view the call stack at the point where your debugger stops. I am not aware of the last point where we can set a breakpoint and there is no call to anything after that point?

Comment: Profiler may be tool you are looking for.

Comment: You might find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531695/how-to-print-the-current-stack-trace-in-net-without-any-exception This allows you to log the stack trace at any point in your application without stepping into the code.

Answer (score 1):

try using [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) its gives you all details (including **call stack**)

[image]