# Get method call stack of a c# application

Tags: c#

Is there a way to see the methods call stack of an application while its running? I have a thrid party application which is not working correctly and I would like to see what methods are being called in what order? Are there any simple tools for that? I couldnt find much in google except ants performance profiler but that is overwhelming my issue and it coasts something

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print the current Stack Trace in .NET without any exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531695/how-to-print-the-current-stack-trace-in-net-without-any-exception)

Comment: Only near dupe imo. It should definitely be linked though.

Comment: i do not have the source code, thats the problem, i need an external tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do it from `C#` code it should be enough to use `StackTrace` class and inspect `StackFrame` collection

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
var frames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
foreach(var frame in frames)
{
   var methodDescription = frame.GetMethod();
   Console.WriteLine(methodDescription.Name);
}
```

There are also other helpful properties in the frame like file name / number / lines etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PerfView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/09/improving-your-app-s-performance-with-perfview.aspx), which is free and can take snapshots of the stacks as the application is running. Sometimes these stacks are incomplete as there is not enough symbol information, but I have had great success using that on production machines where I was unable to instrument the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jetbrains tools:

https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/help/Call_Stack.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Navigation/stackTraceExplorer.html

Hope these will help :)