# How to create Exception instance in C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, error-handling, sdk, crashlytics

I'm [upgrading](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/api-changes#recordcustomexception_is_now_logexception) Crashlytics sdk from Fabric to Firebase for Unity3d project and trying to adapt api-changing for exceptions catching.

I need to construct Exception instance from next arguments:

```
void OnLogMessageReceived(String log, String stackTrace, LogType type)
```

Now I have

```
Crashlytics.Log(log);
Crashlytics.Log(stackTrace);

Exception exception = new Exception(type);
Crashlytics.LogException(exception);
```

Is it possible to send `stackTrace` and get it pretty structured like it was in Fabric?

Comment: Is this a dupe of [Attach StackTrace To Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093261/attach-stacktrace-to-exception-without-throwing-in-c-sharp-net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Wrapper works well:

```
    class WrappedException : Exception
    {
        private string oldStackTrace;

        public WrappedException(string message, string stackTrace) : base(message)
        {
            this.oldStackTrace = stackTrace;
        }

        public override string StackTrace
        {
            get
            {
                return this.oldStackTrace;
            }
        }
    }


    void OnLogMessageReceived(String log, String stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        var exception = new WrappedException(type, stackTrace);
        Crashlytics.LogException(exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Zubair from Fabric/Firebase. With the release of Firebase Crashlytics for Unity, Developers already using the Fabric Crashlytics SDK might need to make some minor changes to their code when upgrading to Firebase Crashlytics. [This guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/api-changes) will provide details on the specific changes to the API, the reason for the change, and helpful suggestions where workarounds are required.

Comment: Hello, Ohh. I see workaround now, but It will be cool to check some any example.